# Solving PDE by characteristic Methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Find the general solution of the following PDE
>   $$x\,\partial_xw - y\,\partial_yw = 0 .$$

Can someone help me with this

I tried it and I get $$C1=(y/x)$$  meaning $$F(w1) = F(y/x)$$but when I try to verify the answer I dont get the null answer as required

Solved

Comment: What is $u_{1}$ supposed to be? And it shouldn't be the same $F$ used in the final solution on both sides of the equation. Also, $$C_{1} = xy$$

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic method yields
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{dy}{y}
$$
and so, the right answer is
$$
xy=C.
$$
Then, if you write $u=u(xy)$, you should be able to see that this solves the equation.

Comment: Oh my bad I had a mistake taking the e^(-ln(x)) , thanks alot